# How to check if a group of numbers are represented from each decile?

Tags: python

With a fixed size, 6 elements, group of numbers (a tuple or list) created from a range of number 1-49 that cannot repeat.

Example

```
[1, 13, 24, 25, 19, 48]
(1, 13, 24, 25, 19, 48)
```

**How can we check if all the deciles are represented in the tuple/list?**

By decile I mean groups of number:

- 1 - 9
- 10 - 19
- 20 - 29
- 30 - 39
- 40 - 49

What I have tried (I think it works, I am still posting the question for possibly better answers):

```
def checkAllDecilesRepresented(tuple):
  d0 = 0
  d1 = 0
  d2 = 0
  d3 = 0
  d4 = 0

  for i in tuple:
    if 0 < i < 10:
      d0 = d0 + 1
    if 9 < i < 20:
      d1 = d1 + 1
    if 19 < i < 30:
      d2 = d2 + 1
    if 29 < i < 40:
      d3 = d3 + 1
    if 39 < i < 50:
      d4 = d4 + 1

  return d0 and d1 and d2 and d3 and d4
```

Comment: `[1, 13, 24, 25, 19, 48]` is a **list**, not a **tuple**

Comment: @rbp I'm going to leave it as a list because answers have already used list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having to create a 2nd set or iterating the 1st set

```py
alldeciles = len({x // 10 for x in l}) == 5
```

Edit:

Turned into a lambda:

```
alldec = lambda l, upperlimit: len({x // 10 for x in l}) == upperlimit // 10
```

Applied to the question:

```
l = [1, 13, 24, 25, 19, 48]
alldeciles = alldec(l, 50)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could find out which decile a number belonged to by floor-dividing it by 10:

```
>>> seq = [1, 13, 24, 25, 19, 48]
>>> deciles = {x//10 for x in seq}
>>> deciles
{0, 1, 2, 4}
>>> deciles == set(range(5))
False
```

Since we know that all numbers are >= 1, we don't have to worry about the fact that 0 would also have a decile number of 0.

Comment: very pythonic. you can also do it using set difference `set(range(5)) - deciles == set()`

Answer (score 5):

```
s = set(x//10 for x in l)       # get the deciles
all(x in s for x in range(5))   # check all deciles
```

Which will return `False` for your example.

Comment: This approach could be faster in the case of a really large number of deciles to check because it doesn't require materializing a set to compare to.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to use numpy. In your case, considering the extreme case, the difference between two decile could not larger than 19. You could use numpy to calculate the difference of two neighbor numbers.

```
import numpy
olist = [1, 13, 24, 25, 19, 48]
diff = numpy.diff(sorted(olist))

print (v < 20).all()
```

This will returen `False` to you.